# Dynamic Sheet Name capture through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one query as i am running below set of do while VBA code and getting error as code is not able to find exact sheet name as "New Consolidated Forecast " *(which have space at last in the sheet name)*.

Also some of the excel templates have sheet name as "New Consolidated Forecast" (without space).

So is there any way to do the compilation as dynamic no matter that particular sheet name have space or not.

[VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejqo8.png)

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV6uu.png)

Thanks for you help in advance :)

Comment: What do you do if your workbooks has both `"New Consolidated Forecast "` and `"New Consolidated Forecast"`?

Comment: @GSerg the workbooks has either "New Consolidated Forecast  " or "New Consolidated Forecast" not both